# how to select specific columns in a table by using np.r__ in dataset.loc and deal with string data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn

I would like to classify a problem which its data rows are something similar to [image: some rows of tables]

In order to divide to test train data:

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

```
Method 1:
X = dataset.loc[np.r_[0:5, 7:26]].values
y = dataset.loc[np.r_[6]].values

Method 2:
X = dataset.loc[:, ['x1', 'x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8','x9','x10','x11','x12','x13','x14','x15','x16','x17','x18','x19','x20','x21','x22','x23','x24','x25','x26']].values
y = dataset.loc[:, ['y']].values
```

The first method  encounters this problem:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [24, 1]
```

while the second one is OK. I do not like to write all of the columns but I do not know how to solve the problem of first method.

Also, since the data is string I encounter this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'id8053'
```

I tried to solve with:

```
X = X.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[1])
y = y.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
```

but I encounter this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: why don't you use iloc for X?

Answer (score 1):

`np.r_` should work fine in your case. `Method 1` missed the rows. You slice on integer index-columns (i.e, slicing by integer position of columns), so you need to use `.iloc` with `np.r_` for columns and specify `:` for rows

Try this (*note the right-end of slices in `np.r_` got added `1` because `.iloc` ignore the right-end while `loc` keeps it*)

```
Method 1:
X = dataset.iloc[:, np.r_[0:6, 7:27]].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, np.r_[7]].values
```

Comment: Thanks but I have another problem Would you please take a look at it?

Comment: @user10296606: you call `values` on the slice of  dataframe `dataset` which returns numpy array . Function `apply` doesn't exist in numpy, so it errors out.